# how to delay the action, rather than the response

Tags: jquery

So I have a drop down rollover effect, but I only want it to work if someone hovers over the element more than .5 secs.

```
$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#cart_status').hide();
    $('#cart_contents').stop(true,true).delay(500).slideDown('#cart_contents');
});
$('#cart_nav2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#cart_contents').slideUp('#cart_contents');
});
```

So currently the 'cart_contents' element will show .5 secs after mouse enter, but I want it to show only if the cursor has hovered for more than .5 secs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to change delay time `600`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer based solution like

```
var navContentSliderTimer;
$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function () {
    navContentSliderTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cart_status').hide();
        $('#cart_contents').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
    }, 500);
});
$('#cart_nav2').mouseleave(function () {
    clearTimeout(navContentSliderTimer)
    $('#cart_contents').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: That should be `clearTimeout` instead of `clearTimer`. Also missing a semicolon on that line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function is being called as soon as you hover over #cart_nav2. You're just delaying the animation, but the animation will always occur. If you move the mouse, then you immediately call the slideUp animation. So if you quickly rollover the element, it will immediately slideup (even if it can't) then .5 seconds later it will slide down. Try this

```
$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#cart_status').hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('#cart_nav2').is(':hover')) {
            $('#cart_contents').stop(true,true).slideDown('#cart_contents');
        },500) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is just an illustration of an idea (not tested):

```
isHovering = false; // should have a "global enough" scope.

$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function(){
    isHovering = true;
    var date = new Date();
    var startTime = date.getTime()
    do while (isHovering and date.getTime() - startTime < 5000) {
    // can use small delay here
    } 

    if (isHovering) {
         $('#cart_status').hide();  
         $('#cart_contents').('#cart_contents');
    }
});

$('#cart_nav2').mouseleave(function(){
    isHovering = false;
    $('#cart_contents').slideUp('#cart_contents');
});
```